# What is the easiest way to avoid using banks while still being able to store money safely?

Tags: savings, bank-account, netherlands

I have had a bank account since I can remember, which I mainly used for saving money & having a physical card to spend money with. For a long time, this his seemed a logical thing to do as I would get interest over my savings. However, currently the interest is 0% and there is a possibility of it going negative in the future. Therefore, **I see no point in using a bank besides for storing my money safely**. I do not like the feeling of them using my money to make (*lots of*) money (e.g. by investing in the weapon industry), while I get nothing in return.

Therefore, **I am looking for a way to store large amounts of money safely and stable** without others being able to "use" my money. I do not care about interest, I just want to avoid using banks<sup>1</sup>. What would you recommend? I have considered the following options:

- Cash (highly unsafe, but very stable)
- Crypto / stablecoin (decently safe, but fluctuating value)

<sup>1 I don't mind storing small amounts of money so I can use a physical card, although a full "bank-less" option is preferred.</sup>

Comment: What incentive would anyone have to store your money safely for nothing in return?

Comment: "Besides storing my money safely". If you don't count that as "anything in return", then by all means, take your money out. But that isn't "nothing".

Comment: It sounds like you're not trying to get any benefit to yourself by taking your money out of the bank; you're only trying to prevent other people from benefiting. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Just FYI, the interest rate is zero precisely because the bank currently can't use your money to make more money (certainly not lots of money). There's a massive surplus of liquidity in the whole sector, all banks have much more money than they can practically invest, so they don't benefit at all from further deposits (they're practically useless to them while they still have to provide all the usual services).

Comment: Note that in addition to storing your money, your bank also allows you to easily make payments to other people/businesses, and receive payments from them.  (Or at least my US bank does, and I don't believe it's unusual.)   As for cryptcurrency being a safe way to store money, have you seen the news this weekend?  Dropping 17% in a day, or 50% since the start of the year (Bitcoin - others saw similar drops) is hardly my idea of safe :-(

Comment: How much money are we talking about (order of magnitude) and on what time frame? If sufficiently large on both accounts, investing in things like real estate may be a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of a bank, look to your local hometown community credit union.

Credit unions are member-owned, not-for-profit organizations that exist for their members’ benefit. Proceeds from their services stay in the local community and help  the credit union provide better investment rates and lower borrowing rates for their members. In most countries, your deposits are as safe and as government-insured as any bank, and offer all the same convenience services as banks.

If you are looking for a safe place to store money, but don’t like the idea of a bank, a credit union is a great choice.

---

Note: This answer is applicable to most countries, but apparently in [the Netherlands, credit unions are focused on entrepreneurs needing business loans](https://business.gov.nl/financing-your-business/funding-and-loans/funding-by-private-investors-or-banks/credit-unions/), so this answer does not seem to apply to the OP.

Comment: Just don't choose the Boeing Employees' Credit Union, if you don't want to be involved with weaponry!  (Or PenFed or Navy Federal). :)

Comment: The question was edited after your answer to clarify that it's about the Netherlands, so this may not be relevant any more.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Apparently, [credit unions in the Netherlands](https://business.gov.nl/financing-your-business/funding-and-loans/funding-by-private-investors-or-banks/credit-unions/) are focused only on small business loans, so it seems that this answer is not relevant to the OP.

Comment: Credit Unions have different names in different countries.  In the UK they are called building societies.

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica That's a little misleading. There's a bunch of retail credit unions in the Netherlands. Together they form a federation called [Rabobank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabobank). However, some people tend to perceive it as one of the three big Dutch banks (together with ABN Amro and ING, both traditional big banks).

Answer (score 1):

Usually your brokerage will store excess cash in a sort of money market account that does generate some nominal (though not real) income. If you are okay with storing some money in the bank, and allowing the connection between broker and bank, that might be a decent option if you combine it with physical cash on hand.

I think that solves the issue of crypto (volatility) and excess cash (risk of ruin/robbery), though does come with the downside of a lag time for use (i.e. transferring back to the bank and then withdrawing might not be instantaneous, depending on your broker).

Comment: Can you explain further how depositing money with a brokerage is different than depositing money with a bank in terms of the OP’s stated objections to banks?

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a way to store large amounts of money safely and stable

- Like it or not, that's what banks are for.
- If not a savings account, then look at Fixed Deposits.
- For the long term, look at government bonds.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use a safe deposit box(kluis)

Mostly used for jewelry & documents, but you can most likely also place Cash or Crypto in there. Maybe cheaper than to place a safe and security in your own house.

Comment: Safe deposit boxes cost money.  And they can get lost.

Comment: Cash in safe deposit boxes can cause problems related to anti money laundering laws.  Most (all) banks will instruct you to not leave cash.